# Элементы JSX не могут иметь несколько атрибутов с одним именем. React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

Почему когда я указываю тегу `input` атрибут name в React, выдает эту ш

```
[{
    "resource": "/src/app/components/thumbnails/ThumbnailListItem/index.js",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "17001",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Элементы JSX не могут иметь несколько атрибутов с одним именем.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 47,
    "startColumn": 25,
    "endLineNumber": 47,
    "endColumn": 29
}]
```

return компонента:

```
return (
        <div className="card-container">
            <div className="card__thumbnail-wrapper">
                <img
                    className="card__thumbnail-img"
                    src={image}
                    alt=""
                    onClick={handleThumbnail}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="card__tools-wrapper">
                <label className="checkbox">
                    <input
                        className="card__tools-checkbox"
                        id={inputId}
                        type="checkbox"
                        onChange={handleCheckboxClick}
                        // name="toDelete"
                    />
                    <span></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: где-то рядом в коде не используются похожие инпуты?

Comment: нет, рядом ничего нет, я обновил код в вопросе